# How to pass click from activity UI to map fragment to change map to MAP_TYPE_HYBRID

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, onclicklistener

I have an activity that holds my map fragment.  I have written the UI xml in the activity and there is a button in this activity that is displayed over the map fragment.  When the map is shown on the screen, the user can click this button and it will change the map from normal maptype to hybrid maptype.  In other words, I want to change the map to GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID.

What I have tried:
I set an onclick listener on the button and put that in the map fragment under onMapReady like this:

```
mapType_hybrid = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapType_hybrid);
mapType_hybrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            }
        });
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens.

Am I missing something like setting the click listener in the wrong place?  I tried setting it in onCreate but it didn't seem to like that and crashed.  Should I try passing a value from the activity to the map fragment, if so how should I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell why your app crashes when you set the `OnClickListener` within the `onCreate` method since you didn't provide your full code, but try the working code below for demonstration and guidance on how changing the map type on a button's click can be implemented.

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch to Hybrid Map" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me out.

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)